# How to send multiple image as response in node.js

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, mongodb

i have stored more image in mongodb by using like this

```
exports.save = function (input, image, callback)
{
    db.collection("articles", function (error, collection)
    {
      collection.save(input, {safe: true}, callback);
    });
}
```

i have retrieved all image from db.

```
find().toArray(function(err,result)
{
     console.log(result.length)//length is 5
     for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
     {
                res.contentType(results[i].imageType);
                res.end(results[i].image.buffer, "binary");
     }
});
```

how to convert this image as binary and how to send response to client.i have tried for loop but i got this error  can't set header after send res.........how to solve

Comment: how will you use the images in the group and why are you grouping them in one response ? it will help us answer your question

Comment: are you trying to stream the images (like video) or send multiple images to download in one go (like file attachments in an email)? if you're streaming, you probably want to implement something like motion jpeg: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG

Comment: database contains 10 images. when you click on show button i have to show all images on browser. when you click on one image i have to show that particular one image into new tap. r u understood my requirement ?

Comment: How big are the images? If they're tiny you could always base64 encode them and send them in a big JSON array

Comment: Consider using the _spdy_ protocol. It's supported by some modern browsers and the [spdy node.js library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spdy) supports fallback for old ones.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to send multiple images within a one single response, I guess. But maybe you could try to merge those images somehow within your loop, and then send a one big image which will consists of your N images merged together.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a similar problem. You need to pass your 'results' array to a Jade template (for example) or manually create an HTML page with the images that you find (not the data) - rather virtual links to the actual images.

```
res.render('image_list.jade', {results:results});
```

Then your template might look like :

```
block content
  div.container
   header
    h1 Images in a list
   div#images
    - each result in results
   div.myimage
     img(src='http://localhost:3000/oneimage'+result._id)
```

In your app.js you would need to provide a route `/oneimage` that returns a single image (data) as you have done in your code (i.e replace `findAll(...)` with `findOne(...., id, ...)`